# PHP script throws multiple errors on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have a php script calling an https api in ubuntu. When I run the script I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  require_once(../functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/push.php on line 2
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/push.php on line 2

SSL is enable in php (as seen on the phpinfo() page). On the server I have the following php's: `5.5/ 5.6/ 7.0/ 7.1/ 7.2/`

Any ideas how may I fix this?

I am trying to fix my script so it would run correct.

The failed to open file is a strange error since the file exist and can be opened. The function.php file is the one containing the call to the https API. So I think PHP is throwing a strange error due to the warning.

Edit2:
The path `/usr/lib/php/20151012/` is owned by `root`. I am running the script with `root`.

`functions.php` is in the correct folder.

Comment: You have two warnings and an error. Which one are you trying to fix?

Comment: I added an edit. I am trying to fix them all.

Comment: First one, most of the times because of not having the correct permission to the folder. Make sure the user that **"run the script"** owns the `/usr/lib/php` folder and content within. Second one, is the `functions.php` file in `/var/` folder? The third one seems to be same as first, it might not.

Comment: Added a new edit. Edit2

Comment: Wait... why is your Ubuntu server asking for DLL files??? Did you copy your php.ini file from a Windows machine?

Comment: no. The ubuntu machine is a VPS, so no windows file. I was wondering the same thing.